# Strange behaviour with actionButton, when I try to display multiple plots

Tags: r, shiny

I observed some strange behavior with `actionButton`, particularly when it is pertaining to plotting. Below is my example :

Basically, in my App, I have an `actionButton` and 2 report sections each section contains a standalone plot. At the time of initialization, I will have 2 different linear plots. However when User click on `actionButton`, then 2 different plots with random values to be generated.

However strangely I saw that, when User clicks `actionButton`, only one plot is displaying over the screen. However at the time of initialization, both the plots are displayed.

Any explanation what causes this strange behavior?

My ShinyApp :

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(
   fluidRow(column(6, offset = 3, actionButton("Run", label = "Run")))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(column(12, style = "background-color:White;", plotOutput("Chart1", height = '475px'))),
    fluidRow(column(12, style = "background-color:White;", plotOutput("Chart2", height = '475px')))
  )
))

server = function(input, output) {
      Values = reactiveValues(default = 0)
                        observeEvent(input$Run, {
                                Values$default = input$Run
                            })

        Plot = eventReactive(input$Run, {                                                       
                        Plot1 = plot(rnorm(100))
                        Plot2 = plot(rnorm(100))

                        return(list('Plot1' = Plot1, 'PLot2' = Plot2))
                    })

        output$Chart1 = renderPlot({
                if (Values$default == 0) {
                        plot(1:100)
                    } else {
                        Plot()$Plot1
                    }
            })
        output$Chart2 = renderPlot({
                if (Values$default == 0) {
                        plot(200:100)
                    } else {
                        Plot()$Plot2
                    }
            })
    }

 runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use:

```
server = function(input, output) {


  output$Chart1 = renderPlot({
    if (input$Run == 0) {
      plot(1:100)
    } else {
      plot(rnorm(100))
    }
  })
  output$Chart2 = renderPlot({
    if (input$Run == 0) {
      plot(200:100)
    } else {
      plot(rnorm(100))
    }
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I am not sure exactly why (although it seems related to `plot`) it does not work but your code works with ggplot2:

```
server = function(input, output) {
  Values = reactiveValues(default = 0)
  observeEvent(input$Run, {
    Values$default = input$Run
  })

  Plot = eventReactive(input$Run, {         

    df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100))
    df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100))
    Plot1 = ggplot(data =df, aes(x= x, y=y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
    Plot2 = ggplot(data =df2, aes(x= x, y=y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()

    return(list('Plot1' = Plot1, 'Plot2' = Plot2))
  })

  output$Chart1 = renderPlot({
    if (Values$default == 0) {
      plot(1:100)
    } else {
      print(Plot()$Plot1)
    }
  })
  output$Chart2 = renderPlot({
    if (Values$default == 0) {
      plot(200:100)
    } else {
      print(Plot()$Plot2)
    }
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: While above suggestion displaying result, however I still not sure where my code went wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Bogaso, I am not sure why but see edits for a ggplot2 alternative with your code.

Comment: Thanks MLavoie. However it is really strange that my code didnt work as intended. Should it be reported as bug?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. But if the answer helps you, you can accept it. I would appreciate it.